How to use Pandas date_range to generate monthly data at begging of the random start time?
I'm trying to generate a date range of monthly data where the day should be started from the given date
pd.date_range(start='13/04/2024', end='13/6/2024', freq='M')

This generates ['2024-04-30', '2024-05-31'], I just want 13/04/2024, 13/05/2024, 13/06/2024...
I've understood the usage of freq M & MS but I need solution for my problem

What if your start date was January 30th? What value would you expect for February?

Any month we will be considering as 30days from the start date, if it is jan 30 2024 we need to get it as feb29th, if there is no leap year we need to get as march1st

But a fixed 30 days from the start date won't give you the same day of each month...

Got your point, without using this static 30days… we may use relativedelta from the dateutil package where we can get exact 30days, that solves the problem.

For frequency, try to use freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1) instead of freq="M"

@Triky it is working for other dates but if we gave start date as jan 30 we are getting wrong results after feb29. Every month date is given at 29th only

You can try to add pd.Timedelta to monthly date range:
out = pd.date_range(start="04/01/2024", end="06/01/2024", freq="MS")
print(out + pd.Timedelta(days=12))

Prints:
DatetimeIndex(['2024-04-13', '2024-05-13', '2024-06-13'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


This wouldn't work properly if the start date was the 30th of January

You can use a for loop to generate the dates and it will work pretty much the same.
periods = 3
start_date = pd.to_datetime('31/01/2024', format='%d/%m/%Y')
dates = [(start_date + pd.DateOffset(months=month)).date() for month in range(0, periods)]

End result:
[datetime.date(2024, 1, 31), datetime.date(2024, 2, 29), datetime.date(2024, 3, 31)]

